# Put array values ​in `usecallback deps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have created a member registration function.

I want to pass the value of `formState.values` ​​from `useCallback Hook` to `axios.post`.

However, when I put `formState.values` in `useCallback` dependencies in the `handleSubmit` function, a `',' expected.` type error occurs.

What should I do? You need to put the `values` array values ​​in `formState` as `axios argument`.

Can't you put `formState.values` in deps, axios argument values like this?

How do I pass the value value as an argument?

```
const [formState, setFormState] = useState<formState>({
    isValid: false,
    values: {},
    touched: {},
    errors: {},
});


const handleSubmit = useCallback((event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
   
    axios.post<Login>(
        'http://www.minsususu.com/login',
        {formState.values},
        {
            withCredentials: true,
        },
    )
    .then(response => {
        const { accessToken } = response.data; 
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        router.history.push('/');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

}, [formState.values])
```

Comment: `',' expected.` is not a type error. What tool exactly is throwing this error, and where?

Comment: `{formState.values}` is indeed a syntax error, but this has nothing to do with `useCallback`

Comment: `{values: formState.values}` would be right. or what ever variable you are expecting to be. also could be `{...formState.values}`

Answer (score 0):

would say the problem is in the post call:

```js
axios.post<Login>(
  'http://www.minsususu.com/login',
  formState.values, // or {values: formState.values}
  { withCredentials: true },
)
```